# Accessing a tag from an iFrame to its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have seen a few example posts of this, but I seem to be a little stumped why none of them work.

Here is a stack view of what I am trying to achieve:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
    <div>Some stuff, images, text</div>
    <div><audio id="audio"><source> src="me.mp3" /></audio></div>
    <div>Some stuff, images, text</div>
    <div>
        <iframe src="file.html">
          #document
            <html>
                <head>...</head>
                <body>
                    <div><button id="stopPlay">Stop Play</button></div>
                </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div>Some stuff, images, text</div>                

    </body>
</html>
```

It has been suggested that to access the audio tag, you would use something like:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('audio');
```

Which gives me an origin error, even though both files are on the same server.  So I add, again as suggested `document.domain = "me@me.com"` and place this within the iframe, and parent. But still gives me an error that relates to the DOM.

As I am looking to go up the stack, and then search down it to find the element, how would I go about doing this, when other suggests have worked for others ?

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my end, is this your exact code? I literally copy pasted it to two files and i was able to manipulate the audio tag from within the iframe. i used localhost as a domain.

Comment: This is the error I get:  > [Error] Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
 
Error in playparent: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.parent.document.getElementById')

Comment: If I add the `document.domain = "me@me.com"` I get this Error in playparent: Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I was able to reproduce this error is when using the local file system, It seems you're trying to access your html file from the local file system.

`file://c:/wamp/www/foo.htm` - that's the only way I could find to reproduce this, and this is a known bug for chrome. Also makes sense in some regrd, as there is no `domain`, thus the origin is `null`

Comment: Okay, so if I add this to a server, I should get a different result.  I am using Safari at the moment.

Comment: Yea it should work perfectly. I suggest you install some local hosting on your machine(wamp/xamp), this will allow you to better testing! also, next time mention you're loading from the file system :P

Comment: Thank you, I should have realised this.  Thank you again @Patrick